# String comparison C#

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I have thousands of time records in the sorted list.
They are at the format:

```
public static string mTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff";
```

The list is sorted in chronological order.
I retrieve a range of records from the list. The resulting range is between 2 times: t1 and t2 and it works fine...

```
string t1 = startTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
string t2 = endTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
List<string> results = fileNameList.FindAll(s => (String.Compare(s, t1, true) > 0) && (String.Compare(s, t2, true) < 0));
```

Now, will my comparison/retrieval still work if I append a random number at the end of the time record...Based on what I know about string comparisons it will break the comparison... Will it?

Comment: Um... You can't just add a few in a test case and figure this out yourself? You don't have a test version of your app and some test data? You really should learn to put some effort into figuring things out yourself before posting. What happens if your internet connection goes down? Do you just sit and twiddle your thumbs until it comes back?

Comment: Oh, the humanity! Comparing `DateTime`s by converting to strings is fraught with danger. `DateTime` structs are directly comparable. Read the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let's try another one. Directly from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx):

> if the two strings compare equal to the end of one string, and the other string has characters remaining, then the string with remaining characters is considered greater

Therefore, your first comparison (`String.Compare(s, t1, true) > 0`) will return true if `s` is longer than `t1` and the rest of the characters are the same. Otherwise, if both `s` and `t1` were the same length, the comparison would only return true if `s` is higher-sorted. However, your second comparison (`String.Compare(s, t2, true) < 0`) should not be affected.

**tl;dr**: Yes, adding a random character *can* and will eventually break your system, but only in the case that `s` and `t1` are exactly the same except for the random character.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that even if it does work, it is the wrong approach. Most of the time it is a mistake to put additional information into a field that is intended to be used for a different purpose. It makes the code quite brittle and hard to maintain. Most professional developers would never consider doing this.

Instead, create a class that incorporates the necessary information - which for right now appears to be a string value and a field of some type to represent the random number. You now have a way of easily adding additional functionality to this class over time as the requirements change.

The class should also probably implement IComparable or implement a class off of IComparer in order to use the compare method. See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

If you did add a random character at the end of the strings, couldn't you just use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
public static string mTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff";

string t1 = startTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
string t2 = endTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
List<string> results = fileNameList.FindAll(s => (String.Compare(s.Substring(0, mTimeFormat.Length), t1, true) > 0) && (String.Compare(s.Substring(0, mTimeFormat.Length), t2, true) < 0));
```

This would truncate the strings `t1` and `t2` if they are longer than the format string, thereby circumventing the problem altogether.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about a kludge to work around a (so far non-existent) problem. It's a specific question about the behavior of sorting.